# using jQuery to add and remove textbox with unique IDs

Tags: jquery, count, addition, textinput

I wrote a function to add listitem with a text box and a remove button, everytime the add button was clicked.  i'm also adding a unique id to each new element by adding a number.  the problem happens when i try to remove an element, then add another one, sometimes that number is being duplicated.  ex: I add 4 li's and decide to remove #3.  Then click add new again the new sequence is 1,2,4,3,4 instead of 1,2,4,5,6.  I hope that made sense.
here is my javascript

```
var count = 2;
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newTxtBxLi = $('<li></li>').attr('id', 'newli' + count).appendTo('ul');
    var input = $('<input type="text" id="newinput' + count + '" name="newinput' + count + '" /><input type="button"  id="remove' + count + '" class="remove" value="">');

    $(input).appendTo(newTxtBxLi);

    count++;

    $('.remove').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            //count--;
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });
    });
});​
```

Thanks, in advance

//update
so i was doing some research on stackoverflow, and found a post about performing a check for duplicate id's.  the new code works, but now i have to figure out how to write "find the last id and + 1, then create new li with this new id.
here is my updated code:

```
    $('#add').click(function() { 
var count = $('ul > li').length + 1;
        var newTxtBxLi = $('<li></li>').attr('id', 'newli' + count).appendTo('ul');
        var input = $('<input type="text" id="newinput' + count + '" name="newinput' + count + '" /><input type="button"  id="remove' + count + '" class="remove" value="">');

        $('ul > li[id]').each(function(){
            var ids = $('[id='+this.id+']');
            if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this){
                //console.warn('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
                //find the last id and + 1, then add new listitem    

                }else{
                $(inputAcc).appendTo(newTxtBxLi);
                accomplishCount++;
                }

            });

        $('.remove').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                count--;
                $(this).parent('li').remove();
            });
        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be re-assigning the `click()` handler to all the `.remove` elements on the page every time you click `#add`.

Because of this, you are adding multiple identical click handlers to the `.remove` elements.

Just assign it to the new one you created.

```
var count = 2;
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newTxtBxLi = $('<li></li>').attr('id', 'newli' + count).appendTo('ul');

    var input = $('<input type="text" id="newinput' + count + '" name="newinput' + count + '" /><input type="button"  id="remove' + count + '" class="remove" value="">');

    input.find('.remove').click(function() {
            //count--;
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });

    input.appendTo(newTxtBxLi);

    count++;
});​
```

As an alternative to assigning a new click handler to every `.remove` that is created, you could use `.live()` or `.delegate()` instead.

```
   // Call delegate on the UL when the page loads.
   // Probably a good idea to have an ID on the UL
$('ul').delegate('.remove','click',function() {
            //count--;
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });

var count = 2;
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newTxtBxLi = $('<li></li>').attr('id', 'newli' + count).appendTo('ul');

    var input = $('<input type="text" id="newinput' + count + '" name="newinput' + count + '" /><input type="button"  id="remove' + count + '" class="remove" value="">');

    input.appendTo(newTxtBxLi);

    count++;
});​
```

Or the `.live()` version would look like this:

```
$('ul > li > .remove').live('click',function() {
            //count--;
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });
```

Comment: @Gerald - Did this happen to fix the repeating IDs issue? It didn't seem entirely related, but wasn't sure if it perhaps caused some unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Gerald - I see you have `count--` commented out. Is it commented out in the code you're running as well? I'd imagine you wouldn't want to decrement.

Comment: i tried it both ways, leaving it in and taking it out, and both times i got the same results.  the last number was being duplicated.  I think a check has to be performed before the .appendTo action is called.  that's what i'm trying to figure out now

Comment: @Gerald - That's strange. It should be very simple. Seems like some other code is decrementing it, or it is not getting increment sometimes. Maybe try placing the `count++` at the beginning of the click handler for `#add`.

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of trying to keep track of a manual count you instead made a count a function of how many `li` elements are on your page?  i.e.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    count = $('li').length;
    var newTxtBxLi = $('<li></li>').attr('id', 'newli' + count).appendTo('ul');
    var input = $('<input type="text" id="newinput'+ count +'" name="newinput'+ count +'" /><input type="button"  id="remove'+ count +'" class="remove" value="">');

    $(input).appendTo(newTxtBxLi);

    $('.remove').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure exactly why you wanted the sequence to go 1,2,4,5,6 though, as simply having each one have a unique id should suffice.  But perhaps that was important?

Comment: you're right, the sequence is not important.  Just as long as each one is unique.  That being said, i used your solution and i'm still having the issue where the id's are being repeated.

Comment: This doesn't count the ones that were removed, so you could still have the same issue.